# Angular 2 - form group component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to build a data-driven form, with inputs coming from another component, like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <app-form-group [name]="name"></app-form-group>
    <app-form-group [name]="email"></app-form-group>
    <app-form-group [name]="other"></app-form-group>
</form>
```

The `app-form-group` component will look something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{Name}}</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
  <input class="form-control" [name]="name" [formControlName]="formCtrlName">
</div>
```

The problem is that `formControlName` needs a `formGroup`directive, therefore I get this error:

```
Error : Error in ./FormGroupComponent class FormGroupComponent - inline template:3:58 caused by: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.You'll want to add a formGroup
   directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).
```

Is there any way to get around this issue?

Comment: You will need to implement your own `ControlValueAccessor` as guided here http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use your FormGroup `[formGroup]="signupForm"` in `app-form-group` Component.You can use this Code :

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="signupForm">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{Name}}</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
  <input class="form-control" [name]="name" [formControlName]="formCtrlName">
</div>
```

Comment: How can `signupForm` be visible from the `app-form-group` child component? Don't you need to pass it explicity as in the answer of Bernhard Hochgatterer?

Comment: You must send "Signuoform" as Input

Answer (score 7):

You can use a @Input property to get the reference into the sub-component:

app-form-group.ts:

```
@Input('group')
public signupForm: FormGroup;
```

app.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <app-form-group [name]="name" [group]="signupForm"></app-form-group>
    <app-form-group [name]="name" [group]="signupForm"></app-form-group>
    <app-form-group [name]="name" [group]="signupForm"></app-form-group>
</form>
```

app-form-group.html:

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="signupForm">
   <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{Name}}</label>
   <div class="col-md-9">
   <input class="form-control" [name]="name" [formControlName]="formCtrlName">
</div>
```

For detailed information have a look at this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Answer (score 2):

When you want to implement a custom component for data-binding to an individual value the correct Angular way to do that is to go with the approach where the parent view specifies either `[formControl]` or `[formControlName]`.

```
<app-form-group formControlName="name"></app-form-group>
<app-form-group formControlName="email"></app-form-group>
<app-form-group formControlName="other"></app-form-group>
```

In your child control you need to do the following:

First add the following provider to your `@Component` declaration, so Angular knows your component can work with `[formControlName]` / `[formControl]`

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CountrySelectorComponent),
    multi: true
  }
]
```

Your child component's class then needs to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. This *should* be a fully working example, if not then let me know and I will change the code, I typed it into the browser directly.

```
@Component({
  // Ensure [formControl] or [formControlName] is also specified
  selector: '[formControl] app-form-group, [formControlName] app-form-group',
  templateUrl: './country-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./country-selector.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      // Provide the value accessor
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CountrySelectorComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CountrySelectorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  private value: any;
  private hasHadFocus = false;
  private hasNotifiedTouched = false;
  private propagateChange: any = () => {};
  private propogateTouched: any = () => {};

  public changed(event: any) {
    this.value = event.srcElement.value;
    this.propagateChange(this.value);
  }

  /**
   * Called when (focus) is triggered
   */
  public focused() {
    this.hasHadFocus = true;
  }

  /**
   * Called when (blur) is triggered
   */
  public blurred() {
    if (this.hasHadFocus && !this.hasNotifiedTouched) {
      // Only notify once, and only if lost focus after a focus
      this.hasNotifiedTouched = true;
      this.propogateTouched();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Called when a new value is set via code
   * @param obj
   */
  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.value = obj;
  }

  /**
   * Register a call back to call when our value changes
   * @param fn
   */
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  /**
   * Register a call back to call when our value is first touched
   * @param fn
   */
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.propogateTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

Your `app-form-group` template would look something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{Name}}</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <input class="form-control" (blur)="blurred()" focus="focussed()" change="changed($event)">
</div>
```

1. Add `[formGroup]="signupForm"` to each of your `app-form-group` instances in your main view
2. Implement OnInit in your `app-form-group` control.
3. Add `private controlContainer: ControlContainer` to the constructor of your `app-form-group` component so Angular will inject it
4. Add `public form: FormGroup;` property to your `app-form-group` component.
5. In ngOnInit add the following code

   this.form = this.containerControl.control;

In your `app-form-group` template you would add [formGroup] like so

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="form">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{Name}}</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
  <input class="form-control" [name]="name" [formControlName]="formCtrlName">
</div>
```

This is the method that requires the least amount of code, and is the one I would recommend when you want to embed composite controls that edit multiple pieces of data (like an Address).

From this blog -> https://mrpmorris.blogspot.co.uk/2017/08/angular-composite-controls-formgroup-formgroupname-reactiveforms.html