# ReactiveForms with nested content

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In my project I have two tabs with `ReactiveForms` where the form's content is a nested component. I've tried to fix the error `Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.` according to this stackoverflow answer: [Angular 2 - form group component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895131/angular-2-form-group-component), but I'm still getting the original error. Any ideas how to fix it?

[Plunker Preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/xEjQWa72s3AhBj7oxSgM?p=preview)

**app.component.ts (Parent)**

```
import {Component, ViewChild, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {TabContent} from './tab-content.component';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private inputData;
  private formGroup1;
  private formGroup2;

  @ViewChild(TabContent) content: TabContent;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup1 = new FormGroup({
      inputControler: new FormControl()
    });

    this.formGroup2 = new FormGroup({
      inputControler: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  getData() {
    this.inputData = this.content.state.nativeElement.value;
    //console.log(this.content.state);
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="One">
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup1">
      <tab-content [group]="formGroup1"></tab-content>
    </form>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Two">
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup2">
      <tab-content [group]="formGroup2"></tab-content>
    </form>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
<button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="getData()">GET DATA</button>

<p>Data: {{ inputData }}</p>
```

**tab-content.component.ts (Child)**

```
import {Component, ViewChild, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
  selector: 'tab-content',
  template: `
    <md-input-container width="100%" [formGroup]="group">
      <input #state mdInput placeholder="State" formControlName="inputControler">
    </md-input-container>
  `
})
export class TabContent {

  @ViewChild('state') state;
  @Input() group;

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

Comment: This wont work because there's no formGroup inside the TabComponent. The formGroup has a component scope, then every component with a form should have one.

Comment: So in my case I need to create two identical forms?

Comment: One thing I notice, **@Input() group;** has no type, and It will be undefined until the parent component completes It rendering. You should try to put a type and initialize It somehow, but the way you are doing has some flaws and you will have more trouble with other things.

Comment: Well, in your plunker, removing the `TabContent` from `bootstrap: [AppComponent, TabContent]`, the errors goes away. Take a look on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yWAZqP8MNLR8JQdfXHaZ?p=preview).

Comment: @developer033 is on the nose, bootstrapping a component implies it is an entry component and will be instantiated in code instead of implicitly via the template rendering engine. This results in unusual and breaking behavior from the start. It's a good catch, and one I missed even though I noted that the behavior was very unusual if you *ngIf="group" inside the TabContent itself as a guard (the first one is never not null/undefined).